# add write access to user ubuntu - shared folder cifs-utils

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

I have folder in /media on ubuntu - shared from windows via fstab and cifs-utils. Can I share this folder to other user: "miki" (not root)

```
root@localhost:/media#
drwxr-xrwx  4 root    root 4096 Nov 15 12:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root 4096 Nov 14 06:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 padm    root    0 Nov 15 09:34 Archive
drwxr-xrwx  2 root    root 4096 Feb 25  2019 kekik
```

I have try with:

```
root@localhost:~# sudo chmod -R 757 /media/Archive/
```

but get:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/Archive/': Permission denied
```

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your question may be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution:
need to modify /etc/fstab by changing:

```
//windowsServer/Archive /media/Archive  cifs  username=wundowsuser,password=somepass,uid=1000,iocharset=iso8859-1,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=1.0  0  0
```

and change group of folder (must umont it first!)

```
sudo umount -l /media/Archive
sudo chown miki:miki /media/Archive/
```